Complete iff Compact in Well-Ordered space
Let $T=(S, \leq, \tau)$ a well-ordered set equipped with order topology (defined here).
Definition 1: $T$ is called complete iff every non-empty subset of $T$ has a greatest lower bound (inferior) and a least upper bound (superior).
Theorem 1: $T$ is compact iff $T$ is complete.
I am having some difficulty understanding the proof of the implication "complete implies compact" in theorem 1. In particular,   here there is an a complete proof, and
here there is a clarification of a particular point of the proof.
I will use the notation of wiki-proof:
Let $\mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $S$.
Let $a=\inf(S)$. Let $B=\{y\in S \,|\, [a, y) \text{ has a finite subcover from } \mathscr{U}\}$, and denote $\alpha = \sup(B)$.
I understand that if $\alpha \in U \in \mathscr{U}$ then $U \subset B$. But I don't understand the next logical steps expressed.

Do you really mean well-ordered set? Note that in a well-ordered set, each non-empty set trivially has an infimum, namely its minimum. And a supremum, iff the whole set has a maximum. The references state this theorem for linearly ordered sets!

We took $\alpha$ to be the supremum of $B$.
Now if $\alpha\in U$ then there is some interval $(x..y)\subset U$ such that $\alpha\in (x..y)$
We claim that $\text{sup} B\nless y $
let $A=\{r:r< y\}$
Note that $A=\{r:r< \alpha\} \cup \{r:\alpha\leq r< y\}$.
By assumption, the former set has a finite subcover and $U$ is a cover of the later set. So $A$ has a finite subcover. But that implies $\text{sup}B$ is at least $y$, a contradiction as $\alpha<y$.
So $\alpha$ must be the supremum of $S$ and the open interval containing $\alpha$ would be of the form $(x..\alpha]$
